# Using MVVM Foundation Messenger to Send Data

Tags: wpf, mvvm, messenger

I've been attempting to get to grips with MVVM and am now at the stage of trying to use a messenger. The framework I chose was Josh Smith's [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/), mainly because it's small and I'm fairly new to both C# and the MVVM pattern. So far, implementing a message that triggers a method in a different ViewModel has gone smoothly (I think) e.g. to send a message identified by "NameOfMessage" :-

```
App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues("NameOfMessage");
```

and on the receiving end e.g. a different ViewModel :-

```
App.Messenger.Register("NameOfMessage", DoSomething);

Void DoSomething()
{
// Your code that "does something" here.
}
```

This is all very well and works beautifully; however, it would be great to pass some information along with the message. At the moment it's like sending a postcard to everyone but forgetting to write how amazing your holiday is.

To this end I've tried the following, a property that when set, sends a message under the heading "SentMessage" with the contents of the property SentMessage aka, "_sentMessage" :-

```
 public string SentMessage
    {
        get { return _sentMessage; }
        set
        {
            _sentMessage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SentMessage");
            App.Messenger.NotifyColleagues("SentMessage", _sentMessage);
        }
    }
```

This flags no errors and appears to be fine, my problem is the syntax for subscribing to this message :-

```
App.Messenger.Register("SentMessage", param => { this.ReceivedMessage = (string)param; });
```

I'd like to receive the message and put the string in another property e.g. ReceivedMessage. What I've tried is above (influenced by [Josh's Mediator Prototype](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/)) but this raises an error stating "Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguaments. I guess this is because it's expecting to be pointed to a Method?

If anyone can aid in the correct syntax the help would be greatly appreciated. (This is all written in C# using WPF, .NET Framework 4 and visual studio 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had used MVVM Foundation for a while before I moved to MVVMLight. I think you have to use below syntax to register callback method for a message. (I haven't tested it, just recall from my memory in the old day.)

```
App.Messenger.Register("SentMessage", (Action<String>)(param => { this.ReceivedMessage = (string)param; }));
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much, I've been puzzling over this for quite a while.